# using android aapt in java program

Tags: java, android, linux, runtime.exec, aapt

I have been trying to execute the aapt command through a java program for quite some time now. My hunch is that I should be using the `runtime.exec()` command to make this happen. However, I have looked at other questions and answers and none seem to work for me. 
The command is:

```
 aapt package -u -f -F "/home/jay/testing_FILES.apk" "/home/jay/testing_FILES"
```

where the `/home/jay/testing_FILES` is the original folder and the `/home/jay/testing_FILES.apk` is the packaged name and location of the final apk. Can anyone explain to me how I can make this command run correctly using the aapt and java `runtime.exec()`?

Comment: Could you share some information about how it's running incorrectly?

Comment: It says that it doesn't know what the aapt is and when I tried to put the entire path to the aapt into the command it says: cannot run program, file/directory doesn't exist

Comment: String firstCommand =  " /home/jay/andTools/aapt package -u -f -F '/home/jay/testing_FILES.apk' '/home/jay/testing_FILES' "; this is how i have been trying to input it. Originally i tried this without the /home/jay/andTools/ part

Comment: Does the same command line succeed from the shell prompt?

Comment: Yes it does I can't seem to automate this process through java

Comment: Have you tried using the String[] version of Runtime.exec(), so you can pass each argument as a separate string?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, I know, but try this out:

```
String[] cmd = {"aapt", "package", "-u", "-f", "-F", "/"//home//jay//testing_FILES.apk/"", "/"//home//jay//testing_FILES/""};

Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = null;
try {
    pr = run.exec(cmd);
    pr.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(pr != null){
        close(pr.getOutputStream());
        close(pr.getInputStream());
        close(pr.getErrorStream());
        pr.destroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have tried the below format, but just in case:

```
aapt  package -f -M ${manifest.file} -F ${packaged.resource.file} -I ${path.to.android-jar.library} -S ${android-resource-directory} [-m -J ${folder.to.output.the.R.java}]
```

Also just in case you have not looked at this website: [how to build Android application](http://asantoso.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/how-to-build-android-application-package-apk-from-the-command-line-using-the-sdk-tools-continuously-integrated-using-cruisecontrol/)

hope that helps.

Comment: I've seen this before but how do I run this in my java program? Using java runtime?

Comment: Check that you have "Android SDK platform-tools" installed using the SDK manager

Comment: The problem isn't the parameters to aapt, it's how to invoke aapt (or any Android command, I suppose) via Java.