# Can Android Asset Packaging Tool be used on Android devices?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, aapt

I have successfully extracted the static features of Android application by using *Android asset packaging tool* through `command prompt`. Now I want to use aapt tool to extract static features of android apps installed on device. I am confused about few things.
Whether do I have to add aapt.exe in my android application or it is already available in android device? If I have to add it in my android application ,how can i add the exe file in the android application in order to call it at run time?

Environment: android studio / eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using android aapt in java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511206/using-android-aapt-in-java-program)

Comment: I have checked this link. The path of aapt.exe given in the above link is  the path of aapt on the system/laptop. My question is what would be the path if i use aapt on android device? where should aapt be placed if i want it to run on android device?